# How do I retrieve an image from a database and show it in an image control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have entered an image in sql server database successfully. Now i want to retrieve this image from database and show it in an Image control. I don't want to put any ListBoxes on the page. I wrote in ASP dot Net..

```
Dim MS As MemoryStream
Dim IMG As System.Drawing.Image
Dim FS As FileStream
Dim FI As FileInfo
Dim IMGSTRM As Stream
Dim IMGBYTS As Byte()
Dim ImgData() As Byte

    CMD1 = New SqlCommand("select * from IMG where userid=0", CON1)
    If Not IsNothing(RDR1) Then RDR1.Close()
    RDR1 = CMD1.ExecuteReader()
    If RDR1.Read Then
        IMGBYTS = RDR1!img
        MS = New MemoryStream(IMGBYTS, False)
        IMG = Image.FromStream(MS)
        PIC1.ImageUrl = IMG
    End If
```

The problem is in the bold 2 lines above End If

Comment: Possible duplicate: [convert from Binarydata to image control in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7390983/55209), [Display image from database in ASP.net with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6987433/55209), [How to show a image in database in the image control of Asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2482104/55209)

Comment: You really like your shift/capslock key, don't you?

Comment: Yep, I know it's a bad practice but i always declare my variables LOUD AND CLEAR :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the desktop application this is the solution

Private Sub SqlBlob2File(ByVal DestFilePath As String)

```
    Dim PictureCol As Integer = 0 ' the column # of the BLOB field
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("server=localhost;integrated security=yes;database=NorthWind")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM Categories WHERE CategoryName='Test'", cn)

    cn.Open()
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    dr.Read()
    Dim b(dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, Nothing, 0, Integer.MaxValue) - 1) As Byte
    dr.GetBytes(PictureCol, 0, b, 0, b.Length)
    dr.Close()

    cn.Close()

    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)
    Me.PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
End Sub
```

this is the link where you may want to look at : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321900/en-us

asp.net solution

in case of web page or aspx page you can only show an image on a webpage from an Url, there is first should be a picture webpage as webform2 with only a picture box should have to be there. This page is the image for the webform1.

In this way you can put as much pictures on a page as you want, depending of
course that you make the same amount of pseudo pages (and don't give them
the same name).

I hope it will be a nice pages.

\\
There has to be an imagebox, a button and a label on the webform1

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
If Not IsPostBack Then
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT FileName, PictureID FROM Picture", conn)
da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
cbd = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
dsPictures = New DataSet
da.Fill(dsPictures)
Me.Image1.Visible = False
ListBox1.AutoPostBack = True
Try
ListBox1.DataSource = dsPictures.Tables(0)
ListBox1.DataTextField = "FileName"
ListBox1.DataValueField = "PictureID"
ListBox1.DataBind()
Catch sqlExc As SqlException
Me.Label1.Text = "Database Error" 'sqlExc.ToString
Catch exc As Exception
Me.Label1.Text = "Datbase Connection Failed!"
End Try
conn.Close()
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
Session.Item("img") = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value
Image1.Visible = True
Image1.ImageUrl = "http://localhost/testSQLPlaatjesWeb/WebForm2.aspx"
End Sub
```

///
\\

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
Dim sqlstr As String = String.Format("SELECT Picture FROM Picture WHERE
(PictureID = {0})", CInt(Session.Item("img")))
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlstr, conn)
conn.Open()
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
rdr.Read()
Response.BinaryWrite(CType(rdr.Item("Picture"), Byte()))
rdr.Close()
conn.Close()
End Sub
```

///

Comment: My dear "Me.PictureBox1.Image" is not present in Asp Dotnet. There is ImageUrl Present in it. How should i assign Image1.ImageUrl to System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms) ??

Comment: I have updated my answer please check and let me know if this did worked for you..