# Display images from database to background

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a application that get image from computer and store in database.now i want to display that image in my image controll How can i do this.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: possible dublicate -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482104/how-to-show-a-image-in-database-in-the-image-control-of-asp-net

Answer (score 3):

You can use embedding c# on aspx page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.
Extract the source of image and assign it to HTML image tag's src attribute