# Retrieve image from SQL Server and show in a WPF grid using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I want to retrieve pictures from a SQL Server table in my application written in C# with WPF. Right now I can get all the data, and also the picture file, but I can't see the picture.

I have this code to fetch the data:

The dataGrid is formed by 7 rows, and I want the last row to be the picture. How can I do it?

```
SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection();

SqlConn.ConnectionString = Conexion.Cn;
SqlConn.Open();

string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM datos_personales WHERE [nombre]= @texto_buscar";

SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, SqlConn);

SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@texto_buscar", this.TextFirstName.Text);

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("datos_personales");
adapter.Fill(dt);

dataListado.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

SqlConn.Close();
this.TextFirstName.Text = string.Empty;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a image in database in the image control of Asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482104/how-to-show-a-image-in-database-in-the-image-control-of-asp-net)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza this is for WPF, so not entirely sure your duplicate suggestion applies.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this
You have to determinate what row, field your image is.

```
adapter.Fill(dt);

byte [] data=new byte[0];
data =(byte[])(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
DataGridViewImageCell img = new DataGridViewImageCell();
img.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
img.Name = "Image";
yourdatagridview.Columns.add(img);
```

Comment: It does not work. I use WPF and neithet .Table or DataGridViewImageCell exists.

Comment: I have solved my problem by using Linq To SQL in the main code, and also using a Dictionary in the WPF page binding it to a converter. So the images are showed well.