# How to show profile picture in html without any event in .net mvc

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show profile picture of login user in circle form in my project.For that I wrote one function.And From That function I am getting profile picture.But I cant understand how to call this function in `html` `img` tag.
I tried this

```
<img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="showProfilePic()>
```

here `showProfilePic()` is my function returning profile picture of the login user.

I am using azure blob storage for storing my images.
and this is my javascript function
function showProfilePic() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/contollername/functionname",
            success: function (result) {
                data = JSON.parse(result);
                $('#imgProfilePic').attr('src', "data:"+ data.ContentType +";base64," + data.Content);
            }
        });
    }
so in this I am retrieving images from Runner controllers GetProfilePic() method.

Comment: check your tags .. do you want solution for .net mvc or html5 JavaScript. How did you store images ? In database or in directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve image from database in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482104/how-to-show-a-image-in-database-in-the-image-control-of-asp-net

Comment: the image url constructed by your function need to fed to `img` tag as source to show in html. for showing the image in circular form , you need to create a circle using css3 and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<IMG>` tag to display images stored in the database by calling another ASP page in SRC attribute of `<IMG>` tag.

```
<IMG SRC="ShowPicture.asp?PhotoId=1">
```

where `PhotoId` is the ID stored in the database.

**Following are the steps which needs to be executed:**

```
Create table Users in MS-Access or SQL server.
Create ShowPicture.asp page.
Call this page using <IMG> tag wherever required.
```

Create table with the following structure:

Table name: Users

```
user_id (AutoNumber)
user_name (Text)
user_photo (Ole Object - For MS-Access, and Image data type for SQL server).
```

Code

ShowPicture.asp is used to display images. You need to pass user ID in querystring, and for that user ID, image will be displayed. Following is the code:

```
'Declare Variables..
   Dim sql
   Dim rs
   Dim conn
   Dim userID,str

  userID = Request("PhotoId")
  If userID = "" Then userID = 0

  'Instantiate Objects
  Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  'Open connection
  Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data.mdb")

  'Get the specific image based on the ID passed in a querystring
   str = "SELECT user_photo FROM users where user_id =" & userID
   rs.Open str, conn,3,3
   if rs.eof then 'No records found
       Response.End
   else 'Display the contents
       Response.ContentType = "image/gif"
       Response.BinaryWrite(rs("user_photo"))
   end if

  'destroy the variables.
  rs.Close
  conn.Close
  set rs = Nothing
  set conn = Nothing
```

Please note that `"Response.contentType"` will depend on the type of content you would like to display. For example, to display jpg image, following will be the code:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
```

To use above page for displaying images, following is the example:

```
<IMG SRC="ShowPicture.asp?PhotoId=1">
<IMG SRC="ShowPicture.asp?PhotoId=2">
```

Upload Image

Following example shows how to upload images in database by using ASPSmartUpload component.

Following is the code to upload image:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="saveFile.asp" 
        ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" NAME="UploadForm">
   <center>
   Employee Name : <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="USERNAME" SIZE="30"><br>
   <INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="UPLOADFILE1" SIZE="50">
   </center>
   <BR>
   <center><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Upload" 
             id=SUBMIT1 name=SUBMIT1></center>
</FORM>
```

Code to save the image in the database:

```
Dim myupload
   'declare variables..
   intCount=0

    ' Create Upload Component
    Set myupload = Server.CreateObject("aspSmartUpload.SmartUpload")
    myupload.Upload

    'Create Connection
    Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _ 
              "Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("data.mdb")

    Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
    Rs.Open "SELECT user_id,user_name,user_photo FROM users", Conn,3,3

    'Select each file
    For each file In myupload.Files
        If not file.IsMissing Then 'Check for missing file
            'Add the current file in database
            Rs.AddNew
            file.FileToField Rs.Fields("user_photo")
            Rs("user_name") = myupload.Form("USERNAME")
            Rs.Update
            intCount = intCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    Response.Write(intCount & " file(s) uploaded.")
    'Destroy the objects...
```